# Splitting up a log file line c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, logging

Log file lines in question:

```
[2018-10-25 19:40:34] [Output] : (CHAT-Type) User: message
```

So the date and output can be split by number of characters right?

Then I can parse the date from within the [].

That would leave me with

```
(CHAT-Type) User: message
```

Now I want to split this into Chat Type, Username and message.

This is really hurting my head how I would do all this in c#.

Basically I need it to come out like this:
DateTime
ChatType
User
Message
all separate variables

Comment: What are the values you're trying to extract? `2018-10-25 19:40:34` and `message`?

Comment: We cannot say it by seeing only this single line. Which parts are constant? Which ones are variable and how do they vary? You cannot parse a string without knowing its exact syntax.

Comment: no parts are constant apart from the brackets and [Output] but the datetime will always be the same length

Comment: One sample isn't enough to give good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you split all the values:

```
string inputValue = "(CHAT-Type) User: message";

            int braceCloseIndex = inputValue.IndexOf(')');
            int colonIndex = inputValue.IndexOf(':');

            string chatType = inputValue.Substring(1, braceCloseIndex - 1).Trim();
            string userName = inputValue.Substring(braceCloseIndex + 1, colonIndex - braceCloseIndex - 1).Trim();
            string message = inputValue.Substring(colonIndex + 1).Trim();

            Console.WriteLine($"chatType: {chatType}, userName: {userName}, msg: {message}");
```

Comment: this works perfectly for the chat side of things, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like RegEx kind of a problem :)

Here's a regular expression that matches a single line (with named capture groups)

```
^\[(?'dateTime'.+)\] \[(?'output'.+)\] : \((?'type'.+)\) (?'user'.+): (?'message'.+)$
```

**Regexr link to try online**: https://regexr.com/421p4

Since I used `.+` for all areas, there are no character restrictions. It might break (e.g., if there is no space before and after `:`.) But it can be further improved to be more flexible. If you'd like, I can write one up.

Also, if you're using a method like `file.ReadAllText()`, you need to use the multiline flag to match all lines. (`Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)`)

Otherwise (if you're iterating through the lines, for example,) it doesn't matter because there are no `\n`s in the string.

### The C# code

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...

string pattern = @"^\[(?<dateTime>.+)\] \[(?<output>.+)\] : \((?<type>.+)\) (?<user>.+): (?<message>.+)$";
string message = "[2018-10-25 19:40:34] [Output] : (CHAT-Type) User: message";

var match = Regex.Match(message, pattern);
```

You can access the matches through the `match` variable like this:

```
match.Groups["dateTime"].Value; // "2018-10-25 19:40:34"
match.Groups["user"].Value; // "User"
match.Groups["message"].Value; // "message"
```

Comment: thanks for this but I used the other method.

also for reading the lines I'm using a log file monitor class I found online

Comment: @JamieJ Sure. Though I should mention this solution gives you all parts of the message. Maybe I made it look scary I'm not sure but RegEx is a great solution for these kinds of situations.